# Is it possible to create datasources dynamically in Tomcat 6 without redeploying web application?

Tags: tomcat, datasource

I need to create databases on the fly in my web application. So I need to create datasources for new databases. Is it possible to create datasource in Tomcat 6 without need to redeploy web application every time new datasource is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apparently do it by accessing the Admin app from your own code - see [this thread.](http://www.mail-archive.com/tomcat-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg78457.html)

The other option is to not use container-managed datasources.